# html5 form validation multiple forms with multiple sumbit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have two div which contain a input field and submit on submit click its toggle so first one contains phone number and submit on submit click will show the other div which contains otp field and submit here my html5 form validation not working. so how to perform validation for both forms with two seperate submit on submit click written logic for toggle.In the code snippet first form phone number its skipping validation

```js
$("#num").click(function () {
  $("#otpdiv").show();
  $("#numberdiv").hide();
});

$("#otpbutton").click(function() {
  $("#otpdiv").hide();
  $("#detailsdiv").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-focus">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>Users</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,400i,600,700">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/isthara.css">
 

</head>

<body>
 <form id="ebcharge">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center isthara-header">
   <img class="logo" src="https://erp.isthara.com/assets/IstharaLogoNew1.png" width="10%" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome"  id="numberdiv">
   <h1>Welcome to the EB Charge</h1><br><br><br><br>
   
     Phone Number:
     <input type="tel"  value="" pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Enter Number" required><br><br>
     <input id="num" type="submit" value="submit" required>
   
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome" id="otpdiv" style="display: none;">
   <h1>Welcome to the EB Charge</h1><br><br><br><br>
   
    OTP:
    <input type="tel" value="" placeholder="Enter Number" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="otpbutton" value="submit">
   
  </div>
 
  <div  class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome" id="detailsdiv" style="display: none; margin: 30px;padding: 10px;">
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Name</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Property</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Room number</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Bed number</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Wallet amount balance</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">KWH (G)</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Last read date and time</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Remarks - mandatory</th>
     <td>Godwin</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</form> 
 <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

c for toggle so i cant use single submit also try in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
<input id="num" type="submit" value="submit" required>
```

to that line and validations will work perfectly

```
<input id="num" type="submit" name="numname" value="workingSubmit" />
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-focus">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>Users</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,400i,600,700">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/isthara.css">
 

</head>

<body>
 <form id="ebcharge">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center isthara-header">
   <img class="logo" src="https://erp.isthara.com/assets/IstharaLogoNew1.png" width="10%" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome"  id="numberdiv">
   <h1>Welcome to the EB Charge</h1><br><br><br><br>
   
     Phone Number:
     <input type="tel" value="" pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Enter Number" required><br><br>
     <input id="num" type="submit" name="avto" value="submit">
     <input id="num" type="submit" name="numname" value="working Submit button" />
   
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome" id="otpdiv" style="display: none;">
   <h1>Welcome to the EB Charge</h1><br><br><br><br>
   
    OTP:
    <input type="tel" value="" placeholder="Enter Number" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="otpbutton" value="submit">
   
  </div>
 
  <div  class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome" id="detailsdiv" style="display: none; margin: 30px;padding: 10px;">
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Name</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Property</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Room number</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Bed number</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Wallet amount balance</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">KWH (G)</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Last read date and time</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Remarks - mandatory</th>
     <td>Godwin</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</form> 

</body>
<script>
$("#num").click(function () {
  $("#otpdiv").show();
  $("#numberdiv").hide();
});

$("#otpbutton").click(function() {
  $("#otpdiv").hide();
  $("#detailsdiv").show();

});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't have two submit buttons. The first button, simply advances you further along in the form data entry process, so it should just be a regular button.

Then, on the actual submit button, you've set up a `click` event handler, but with `submit` buttons, you want to handle the `submit` event of the form.

Having said this, are you actually submitting any data anywhere? If not, then you shouldn't be using any submit buttons or forms, just regular buttons.

NOTE:

You've also got `required` on your submit buttons, which doesn't do anything, a button can't be required.

```js
$("#num").click(function () {
  // Force the form to validate
  if($("#txtTel")[0].checkValidity()){
    $("#otpdiv").show();
    $("#numberdiv").hide();
  } else {
    // Show validity message
    $("#txtTel")[0].reportValidity();
  }
});

// It's the submit event of the form you need here
$("#ebcharge").submit(function() {
  $("#otpdiv").hide();
  $("#detailsdiv").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-focus">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <title>Users</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,400i,600,700">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/isthara.css">
 

</head>

<body>
 <form id="ebcharge">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center isthara-header">
   <img class="logo" src="https://erp.isthara.com/assets/IstharaLogoNew1.png" width="10%" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome"  id="numberdiv">
   <h1>Welcome to the EB Charge</h1><br><br><br><br>
   
     Phone Number:
     <input type="tel" id="txtTel" pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Enter Number" required><br><br>
     <input id="num" type="button" value="Continue">
   
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome" id="otpdiv" style="display: none;">
   <h1>Welcome to the EB Charge</h1><br><br><br><br>
   
    OTP:
    <input type="tel" value="" placeholder="Enter Number" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="otpbutton" value="submit">
   
  </div>
 
  <div  class="col-sm-12 isthara-welcome" id="detailsdiv" style="display: none; margin: 30px;padding: 10px;">
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Name</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Property</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Room number</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Bed number</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Wallet amount balance</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">KWH (G)</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Last read date and time</th>
     <td>Godwin </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <th scope="row">Remarks - mandatory</th>
     <td>Godwin</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</form> 
 <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```